# Set value/text to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following [jquery postcode lookup](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/documentation/jquery-plugin) and I am trying to push values and hard code the process in javascript.

I am using the following to give the postcode textbox a valid postcode, and then forcing the button click to find the addresses.

```
document.getElementById("idpc_input").value = "LL17 0PN";
document.getElementById('idpc_button').click();
```

This so far works, after this a dropdownlist appears with the id of 'idpc_dropdown', I am trying to (in javascript or jquery) select an option

Here is what I have done but it does not work

```
 var select = document.getElementById("idpc_dropdown");
 document.getElementById("idpc_dropdown").text = '2 Elwy Cottages Heol Esgob';
```

And also:

```
var desiredValue = "2 Elwy Cottages Heol Esgob"
var el = document.getElementById("idpc_dropdown");
for(var i=0; i<el.options.length; i++) {
  if ( el.options[i].text == desiredValue ) {
    el.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
 Let me explain the process and order, 1- Type in postcode and press the button to find my address 2- a dropdownlist then renders and appears .. I Think this is why it is not working for my desired dropdownlist as its not loaded  when the page is loaded, it is when the button has been pressed

Answer (score 1):

Provided that `i` is the same as the index of the item you wish to select, I'd set the dropdown's `value` attribute to that index:

```
let el = document.getElementById("idpc_dropdown");
for(let i = 1; i <= el.options.length; i++) {
  if ( el.options[i].text == desiredValue ) {
    el.value = i; // here
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: After testing, the code which i offered does work on an ordinary dropdownlist. Let me explain the process and order, 1- Type in postcode and press the button to find my address 2- a dropdownlist then renders and appears .. I Think this is why it is not working for my desired dropdownlist